# Dax formula in Excel Pivot table Column and Row field list

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerquery

I am currently working on a report which is connected to the data source using Power Query, this also append the queries to one sheet then Loads to Pivot table with Data Model enabled. The report is Pivot table and Chart. The issue is because the Data Model is enabled, this makes the Show Item with no data greyed out so I am not able to use it to show all values with no data in the report which is very important in the report. I have tried m query with no success and not I tried the below Dax Formula to show all item with no data in the report.

```
=IF(
   CALCULATE( COUNT('DQR003_RawData  New Depot'[Fix] ) ) = BLANK(),
0,
CALCULATE( COUNT('DQR003_RawData  New Depot'[Fix] ) )

)
```

But unfortunately, when I try to drag the Dax Formula to the column and rows of the pivot table field list as shown below to show the item with no data in the pivot table column and row it gives the below error message:

The field you are moving cannot be placed in that area of the report

How can I can use the Dax formula in the Row Column pivot table field list? Is there any other way I can solve this issue using m query?

Just to simplify things this is the current output:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJpLM.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFa6j.png)

I have also tried this formula but it keeps throwing up error:

```
= if('DQR003_RawData  New Depot'[Fix]=0;BLANK();'DQR003_RawData  New Depot'[Fix] )
```

This Dax function is giving me error, I honestly do not know what else to do. It should just be a click of a button on Show data with no value, but because I have Data model enabled this is greyed out.

Comment: I faced a similar issue once, and I am not sure this will work for you, but I did a Replace Value in M to convert *null* with the text "WASNULL" and then, in the final step in M, I replaced WASNULL back to null.  This pushed the *null* valued rows into the data model where DAX could see them.

Comment: I have tried using the Replace value also tried the m code using IF statement with no success. I result in Dax  as mentioned above using ISBlank but I could not drag this formula in the Column and Row pivot table field list. Is there another way to write the Dax in order for me to drag it into Column and Row list in pivot table field list? Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I used this Dax measure to show data with no value:

```
Fix1:=
    IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(COUNT('table1'[Report]), 'table1'[Report] = "Fix1")),0,
        CALCULATE(COUNT('table1'[Report]), 'table1'[Report] = "Fix1"), 'table1'[Report]), 'table1'[Report] = "Fix1"))
```

I wrote this measure for all the fix in the column so example: Fix1; Fix2; Fix3; Fix4 etc.. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Reference:
[Measures on rows. Here is how I did it. Matt Allington](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/measures-on-rows-here-is-how-i-did-it/)

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: unfortunately, after trying the steps it does not seem to be the appropriate solution to show the data in the column as per the above current and desired output